# I like to add a quantity drop-down In cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add quantity drop-down In cart page

[image]

Customer are able to change quantity by changing drop down option

Comment: you have to add in `app/design/frontend/<Theme_Vendor>/<Your_Theme>/template/checkout/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly review below For adding qty Dropdonw over cart page.

URL : http://www.opencartas.com/magento/how-to-have-a-dropdown-for-the-quantity-39272.html

URL : [Magento2: how to add remove header links conditionally](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162346/how-to-add-remove-header-links-conditionally)