# Magento2: how to add remove header links conditionally

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, magento-2.1.3

how to add remove header links conditionally. I am trying to show my account link only when the customer is logged in. Otherwise it should be hidden. How to do the same using xml files.

Comment: For that use plugin

Comment: @NikhilVaghela, which plugin, please suggest name.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela : So, do you mean it cannot be done using xml, because I am trying to achieve this by making modifications in theme

Comment: check my update ans., it's working

Answer (score 0):

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="vendor_test_layout_load_before" instance="Vendor\Test\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Test/Observer/LayoutLoadBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Test\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements ObserverInterface 
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        // add your condition here 

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $httpContext=$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');         
    $isLoggedIn=$httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

    if(!$isLoggedIn){
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
       $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<body>     
         <referenceBlock name="top.links">           
          <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />            
         </referenceBlock>
        </body>');
    }

       // condition over here

        return $this;
    }    

}
```